# How to store JSON data from a file into an array of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am working on Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse and using HTML 5 and Javascript as well. 
I could manage to parse JSON file that is saved locally in my system though the code below:

```
$.getJSON( "/Users/Documents/workspace2/sample.json", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
    });
    $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-new-list",
        html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Let's suppose this is the JSON file:

```
{"resource":"A","literals":["B","C","D"]}
```

My question is: Is there any possibility to have an array of strings to store these elements that are inside the JSON file after parsing. I am quite new to jQuery and couldn't really manage to see these elements stored in an array of strings, for example. Could anyone help me with this issue please.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do. Can you show us what the desired result of your code should be?

Comment: Well. I am using Arobr javascript for visualisation. At some point, I should show nodes that are labeled with strings. I would like to get from JSON file "A", "B", "C", and "D", store them in an array of string and use them for the Arbor Javascript to get them visualised in nodes. After parsing, what can I do to read or store "A", "B", "C" and "D" as strings in order to be used for later.

Comment: you could save `data`, which is an object at this point, to a variable that is scoped outside of the `getJSON` call but realize `getJson` is an asynchronous operation. So when this runs other things will continue to run until this completes then this will run the callback (the anon function you define in the call), so any variable you set inside of the `getJson` callback may not be available when you need it.

Comment: I would avoid storing presentation detail (i.e. the HTML) in your model, as really you should have separation of concerns i.e. It should be your presentation layer's responsibility to render the view, the data (i.e. your JSON) should be view/presentation agnostic i.e. have no knowledge of presentation detail.

Comment: I have defined an array which is outside the scope of getJson and added the following line: {outer.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" ); After that I added the following line to see the first element of the array: {var node = sys.addNode('The First Element',{'color':'red','shape':'dot','label':outer.get(0)});} Unfortunately I cant get the first element of the string however it is defined outside the scope of getJson. Any idea, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way :

**jsonFile.json**

```
{
    "resource":"A",
    "literals":["B","C","D"]
}
```

**myFile.html**

```
<html>
<head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.getJSON( "jsonFile.json", function( data ) {
                var items = [];
                $.each( data, function( key, val1 ) {
                    items.push( "<li><a href=#'" + key + "'>" + val1 +"</a></li>");     
                });
            });
                $( "<ul/>", {
                "class": "my-new-list",
                 html: items.join( "" )
                }).appendTo( "body" );
            });
        </script>

</head>
<body>
    //result will be displayed here 
</body>
</html>
```

**Output :**

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you for this code. I am nearly there. I have one more problem. When I run your code, it gives me a long list with "Undefined". Any idea please? Your support would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your code is working but it shows me a list of undefined items. As soon as I replace this.command and this.name with key val1 respectively, I get the expected results iteratively. What are this.command and this.name? May you please help me with this?

Comment: this.command returns the value of the command key and this.name returns the value of the name key of the json file i provided.

Comment: I copied and pasted your codes as they are. Unfortunately, I cant see any results so far. I am wondering why!.

Comment: I totally believe your answer is so correct. I think I am having a problem that I cant see the result. I right click on the file and select Open with -> Web browser. I cant understand why it is not working. I copied and pasted your codes as they are though but nothing in there.

Comment: I added it. I copied exactly your codes. I changed the path of the file jquery-1.10.2 to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
var abc = JSON.stringify({"resource":"A","literals":["B","C","D"]});

var ab = JSON.parse(abc);

var arr=$.map(ab, function(value, index) {
   return [value];
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have the json file saved in my local system. I cant copy the content of that file into the variable abc. Is there any solution where I can read the Json file, convert the data into String and display them in html. Thank you